# Change the default remote for push suggestion

Tags: git, push, branch

When I create a new branch and do `git push` for the first time, it fails and gives me a suggestion like so:

```
fatal: The current branch new-branch has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin new-branch
```

How can I change the default remote `origin` that it suggests pushing to? I want it to suggest a different origin that I have added: `git push --set-upstream different-origin new-branch`.

Answer (score 1):

The name printed here is obtained by the function [`pushremote_for_branch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cd3e606211bb1cf8bc57f7d76bab98cc17a150bc/remote.c#L489-L502), which reads:

```
    if (branch && branch->pushremote_name) {
            if (explicit)
                    *explicit = 1;
            return branch->pushremote_name;
    }
    if (pushremote_name) {
            if (explicit)
                    *explicit = 1;
            return pushremote_name;
    }
    return remote_for_branch(branch, explicit);
```

Here, `branch->pushremote_name` comes from the configuration item `branch.name.pushRemote` if that's set.  Meanwhile, `remote.pushDefault` fills in the answer in `remote_for_branch`.  If neither of those supply the answer, the fallback is to use `branch.name.remote`.

Hence:

```
git branch newbranch
git config branch.newbranch.pushremote newremote
```

will guarantee that the default is `newremote`.  But if you don't want to have to run `git config branch.newbranch.pushremote`—and of course it won't already be configured if you just created it—then:

```
git config remote.pushdefault newremote
```

will set a recommendation—and a default—for *every* branch that doesn't already have an explicit pushremote setting.  If that's *too* global, you'll need an explicit `git config branch.newbranch.something`, whether the *`something`* is `pushremote` or `remote`, so that the setting is just for that one branch.

(You can spell it `pushRemote`, as the documentation does, or even `PUSHREMOTE` or `PUshreMOte` or whatever, if you like.  Git internally translates everything to lowercase, and then compares the lowercase names.)

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. The problem with `git config remote.pushdefault newremote` is that it sets the push branch in a way that a `git push` on a new branch actually pushes, rather than issuing a message about no configured upstream. Maybe that's what you meant by "and a default" in "will set a recommendation—and a default—"? What I wanted was to still have this message, but change the remote shown in the message.

Comment: Ah, I had not actually tested it, but yes, that's clearly further than you want this to go. I'm not sure you can get quite what you want out of Git as it stands today.